# How to specify war target artifacts from remote location in Maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Is there a way to specify a list of `war` targets in maven, such that the `war` is not built from source, but copied as-is from a remote location (e.g. artifactory).

My goal is that when I import my maven project into Intellij, there would be a canned list of pre-built wars available for selection as artifacts in the deployment section of IntelliJ Tomcat Server run configuration, the same as local built-from-source wars are.

Comment: Please explain more in detail best with example what you like to do ? A war target does not exist in Maven?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: Along with your (war) Maven project, you want to deploy a predefined list of other wars to the same Tomcat (when you build the project)?

Comment: Yes, it's a microservice architecture, so I have my war service that I work on, and some other microservice dependencies that I want to deploy locally (via intellij-idea run configuration). What I currently do is checkout the code for those, and add their pom.xmls as modules in my toplevel. That works, intellij recognises them as artifacts I can deploy, but involves some amount of management and building. Just getting the prebuilt artifacts recognised would be nicer.